# How to avoid memory leaks from jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, reactjs

**jQuery holds references to DOM nodes in its internal cache until I explicitly call $.remove(). If I use a framework such as React which removes DOM nodes on its own (using native DOM element APIs), how do I clean up jQuery's mem cache?**

I'm designing a fairly large app using React. For those unfamiliar, React will tear down the DOM and rebuild as needed based on its own "shadow" DOM representation. The part works great with no memory leaks.

Flash forward, we decided to use a jQuery plugin. After React runs through its render loop and builds the DOM, we initialize the plugin which causes jQuery to hold a reference to the corresponding DOM nodes. Later, the user changes tabs on the page and React removes those DOM elements. Unfortunately, because React doesn't use jQuery's $.remove() method, jQuery maintains the reference to those DOM elements and the garbage collector never clears them.

Is there a way I can tell jQuery to flush its cache, or better yet, to not cache at all? I would love to still be able to leverage jQuery for its plugins and cross-browser goodness.

Comment: So when you say "navigate away", you're not talking about actually navigating to a new page, right? These are DOM changes made to the current page?

Comment: Correct. I'll clarify the original question as well. Navigation in my React app means a DOM tranformation based on some AJAX result.

Comment: Does the cache flush need to be targeted to just the specific area of the page? If so, can you perform an operation on that area before ReactJS makes its changes?

Comment: As far as I know, the cache flush can be as widespread as needed. I don't personally need jQuery to hold any state on my DOM, so I'd be fine disabling its internal cache altogether. I'm just not sure how baked into the framework it actually is.

As for React -- I don't know when React will tear down and rebuild certain elements. The idea is to make your components completely stateless so you can rebuild them at any time, and then to relinquish all DOM control to the React framework.

Comment: If you need to clear the whole cache, it's simply an object stored at `jQuery.cache`, so you can wipe it out easily with `jQuery.cache = {}`. You'll want to experiment with this to make sure jQuery can recover, otherwise you may need to do more targeted clearing. But it seems like clearing the cache could break whatever jQuery plugin you're using. Do you really need jQuery?

Comment: Breaking my plugin is what I'm afraid of. I don't NEED jQuery per say, but it would be fantastic if I could use it to leverage all the work they do to smooth out browser compat bugs and other utils it provides. Certainly I'm not the only person using jQuery and React together.

Comment: Depends on what browsers you're supporting. jQuery was far more important when IE6/7 were relevant. Anyway, yeah plugins often rely on the cache for event handlers or other data. Seems like ReactJS would want to offer an extension to make it jQuery aware when doing removals and stuff. Frankly, I don't know why people use these big abstractions these days, but to each his own.

Comment: @BrentTraut—sounds like you need to analyse what you are using jQuery for and start replacing it. Browsers are now remarkably consistent. jQuery is a general library that must try to work around every bug and inconsistency in every aspect of browsers. Very few web applications actually need that, there are simple strategies to avoid most browser quirks so you can write much simpler and cleaner code.

Comment: @RobG Perhaps you're right that browsers and frameworks are getting better. But still for the sake of this question, assume that I need to use jQuery because I need plugin support. Rewriting plugins isn't a realistic solution for me.

Comment: @squint Looks like jQuery.cache is undefined anyway. I'm assuming the cache is just a var within jQuery's closure and thus private to external scope.

Comment: Ah, I see they made it private in jQuery 2. If that's the version you're using, then browser issues are definitely minimal without it since IE8 and lower aren't supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your plugin exposes a method to programatically destroy one of its instances (i.e. `$(element).plugin('destroy')`), you should be calling that in the `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle of your component.

[`componentWillUnmount`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#unmounting-componentwillunmount) is called right before your component is unmounted from the DOM, it's the right place to clean up all external references / event listeners / dom elements your component might have created during its lifetime.

```jsx
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount() {
        $(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.jqueryPluginContainer)).plugin();
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
        $(React.findDOMNode(this.refs.jqueryPluginContainer)).plugin('destroy');
    },
    render() {
        return <div ref="jqueryPluginContainer" />;
    },
});
```

If your plugin doesn't expose a way to clean up after itself, [this article](http://ub4.underblob.com/remove-jquery-plugin-instance/) lists a few ways in which you can try to dereference a poorly thought out plugin.

However, if you are **creating** DOM elements with jQuery from within your React component, then you are doing something seriously wrong: you should almost **never** need jQuery when working with React, since it already abstracts away all the pain points of working with the DOM.

I'd also be wary of using refs. There are only few use cases where refs are really needed, and those usually involve integration with third-party libraries that manipulate/read from the DOM.

---

If your component conditionally renders the element affected by your jQuery plugin, you can use callback refs to listen to its mount/unmount events.

The previous code would become:

```jsx
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    handlePluginContainerLifecycle(component) {
        if (component) {
            // plugin container mounted
            this.pluginContainerNode = React.findDOMNode(component);
            $(this.pluginContainerNode).plugin();
        } else {
            // plugin container unmounted
            $(this.pluginContainerNode).plugin('destroy');
        }
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {Math.random() > 0.5 &&
                    // conditionally render the element
                    <div ref={this.handlePluginContainerLifecycle} />
                }
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

Comment: I have not worked with **React** but for now I do it with Angular, and you gave a good point: _you should almost never need jQuery when working with X..._ when X is a library decoupled from the DOM.

Comment: Destroying the plugin and even DOM elements using jQuery's .remove() can both be done in `componentWillUnmount`, but there still plenty of opportunities during your component's lifecycle to have the `render` method tear down and rebuild the DOM. `componentWillUnmount` only covers the *last* one.

Comment: @BrentTraut Good point. I have updated my answer to cover this case.

Answer (score 13):

**jQuery** keeps track of the events and other kind of data via the **internal** API `jQuery._data()` however due to this method is internal, it has no official support.

The internal method have the following signature:

```js
jQuery._data( DOMElement, data)
```

Thus, for example we are going to retrieve all event handlers attached to an Element (via jQuery):

```js
var allEvents = jQuery._data( document, 'events');
```

This returns and `Object` containing the **event type** as key, and an **array of event handlers** as the value.

Now if you want to get all event handlers of a specific type, we can write as follow:

```js
var clickHandlers = (jQuery._data(document, 'events') || {}).click;
```

This returns an `Array` of the *"click" event handlers* or `undefined` if the specified event is not bound to the Element.

**And why I speak about this method?** Because it allow us tracking down the **event delegation** and the event listeners attached directly, so that we can find out if an **event handler is bound several times** to the same Element, resulting in **memory leaks**.

But if you also want a similar functionality without jQuery, you can achieve it with the method **`getEventHandlers`**

Take a look at this useful articles:

- **[getEventHandlers](https://gist.github.com/jherax/968ad4ff8eaa9ceb9159)**
- **[getEventListeners - chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#geteventlistenersobject)**
- **[getEventListeners - firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/GetEventListeners)**

---

### Debugging

We are going to write a simple function that prints the event handlers and its namespace (if it was specified)

```js
function writeEventHandlers (dom, event) {
    jQuery._data(dom, 'events')[event].forEach(function (item) {
        console.info(new Array(40).join("-"));
        console.log("%cnamespace: " + item.namespace, "color:orangered");
        console.log(item.handler.toString());
    });
}
```

Using this function is quite easy:

```js
writeEventHandlers(window, "resize");
```

I wrote some utilities that allow us keep tracking of the events bound to DOM Elements

- [Gist: Get all event handlers of an Element](https://gist.github.com/jherax/968ad4ff8eaa9ceb9159)

And if you care about performance, you will find useful the following links:

- [Leaking Memory in Single Page Apps](http://blog.caplin.com/2013/04/12/leaking-memory-in-single-page-javascript-applications/)
- [Writing Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/)
- [JavaScript Memory Profiling](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)

I encourage anybody who reads this post, to pay attention to memory allocation in our code, I learn the performance problems ocurrs because of three important things:

1. Memory
2. Memory
3. And yes, Memory.

---

### Events: good practices

It is a good idea create named functions in order to **bind** and **unbind** **event handlers** from DOM elements.

If you are creating DOM elements dynamically, and for example, adding handlers to some events, you could consider using **event delegation** instead of keep bounding event listeners directly to each element, that way, a parent of dynamically added elements will handle the event. Also if you are using jQuery, you can namespace the events ;)

```js
//the worse!
$(".my-elements").click(function(){});

//not good, anonymous function can not be unbinded
$(".my-element").on("click", function(){});

//better, named function can be unbinded
$(".my-element").on("click", onClickHandler);
$(".my-element").off("click", onClickHandler);

//delegate! it is bound just one time to a parent element
$("#wrapper").on("click.nsFeature", ".my-elements", onClickMyElement);

//ensure the event handler is not bound several times
$("#wrapper")
    .off(".nsFeature1 .nsFeature2") //unbind event handlers by namespace
    .on("click.nsFeature1", ".show-popup", onShowPopup)
    .on("click.nsFeature2", ".show-tooltip", onShowTooltip);
```

---

### Circular references

Although **[circular references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection)** are not a problem anymore for those browsers that implement the [Mark-and-sweep algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Mark-and-sweep_algorithm) in their **Garbage Collector**, it is not a wise practice using that kind of objects if we are interchanging data, because is not possible (for now) serialize to JSON, but in future releases, it will be possible due to a new algorithm that handles that kind of objects. Let's see an example:

```js
var o1 = {};
    o2 = {};
o1.a = o2; // o1 references o2
o2.a = o1; // o2 references o1

//now we try to serialize to JSON
var json = JSON.stringify(o1);
//we get:"Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

Now let's try with this other example

```js
var freeman = {
    name: "Gordon Freeman",
    friends: ["Barney Calhoun"]
};

var david = {
    name: "David Rivera",
    friends: ["John Carmack"]
};

//we create a circular reference
freeman.friends.push(david); //freeman references david
david.friends.push(freeman); //david references freeman

//now we try to serialize to JSON
var json = JSON.stringify(freeman);
//we get:"Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON"
```

PD: This article is about [Cloning Objects in JavaScript](https://jherax.wordpress.com/2014/07/20/js-clonando-objetos/). Also this gist contain demos about cloning objects with circular references: [clone.js](https://gist.github.com/jherax/05204bdf9eb47eeffdc8)

---

### Reusing objects

Let's follow some of the programming principles, **DRY** *(Don't Repeat Yourself)* and instead of creating new objects with similar functionality, we can abstract them in a fancy way. In this example I will going to reuse an event handler (again with events)

```js
//the usual way
function onShowContainer(e) {
    $("#container").show();
}
function onHideContainer(e) {
    $("#container").hide();
}
$("#btn1").on("click.btn1", onShowContainer);
$("#btn2").on("click.btn2", onHideContainer);
```

```js
//the good way, passing data to events
function onToggleContainer(e) {
    $("#container").toggle(e.data.show);
}
$("#btn1").on("click.btn1", { show: true }, onToggleContainer);
$("#btn2").on("click.btn2", { show: false }, onToggleContainer);
```

---

And there are a lot of ways to **improve** our code, having an impact on **performance**, and preventing **memory leaks**. In this post I spoke mainly about **events**, but there are other ways that can produce memory leaks. I suggest read the articles posted before.

---

*Happy reading and happy coding!*

Comment: You should mention that `$._data()` techniques are using an unsupported method. It could break at any time. Also, there's performance overhead to binding all handlers on the `document`. I certainly wouldn't call it "better". There's a reason they got rid of the `.live()` method, which did exactly that.

Comment: *"...Avoid circular references, it not allows the garbage collector recover the allocated memory..."* That's just flat-out wrong. The whole point of a garbage collector is that it *does* handle stuff like circular references. The article you linked is discussing a different problem entirely that primarily affected old IE.

Comment: In the first comment you have reason, the event bubbling up until it reach the document. 
In the second comment, I am not speaking about old IE, but you have reason again, because all modern browsers can handle the circular references. I will update the post, and change the cyclical references related to serializing JSON (it will be working in futures releases of JSON)

Comment: @squint I appreciate your feedback, I enrich my knowledge when people enlightens me with his knowledge.

Answer (score -8):

How about do this when the user exits the tab:

```
for (x in window) {
    delete x;
}
```

This is much better to do, though:

```
for (i in $) {
    delete i;
}
```

Comment: This is pretty far away from a viable solution. The problem is that jQuery's internals (certainly not global variables) are being maintained even after React completes a render loop which may or may not tear down the DOM.

Comment: Still pretty far off. Your method will now delete ALL properties and methods in jQuery. In order to answer my question, I think you're going to need a more intimate knowledge of the internal jQuery DOM cache.